# I don't know why my 'elif ' and 'else' code does not work

Tags: python, if-statement

```
score = input("What is your score? ")
if score == str(100):
    print('Perfect!')
elif score <= str(range(95, 99)):
    print('Great!')
elif score <= str(range(90, 95)):
    print('Good')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

It works when I type 95 to 100, but it doesn't work when I type other numbers.

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that the output from `str(range(95, 99))` is exactly what you expect?

Comment: The problem is that in the execution the `elif score <= str(range(95, 99)):` is always executed before the other condition, so if you type a number less then the condition `elif score <= str(range(95, 99)):` it always fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ints to compare numbers, not strings:

```
score = int(input("What is your score? "))
if score == 100:
    print('Perfect!')
elif score in range(95, 100): # This 100 catches the 99 case
    print('Great!')
elif score in range(90, 95):
    print('Good')
else:
    print('Fail')
```